# word embedding example in keras predicts different results on each run

Tags: python, flask, tensorflow, keras

I am following the [pretrained_word_embeddings](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings.py) and is saving the model using the following piece of code
`print('Saving model to disk ...')
model.save('/home/data/pretrained-model.h5'')`

I am then loading the pretrained model using 
`pretrained_model = load_model('/home/data/pretrained-model.h5')`

Later the following piece of code for predicting on a different text altogether

```
predict_texts = []  # list of text samples
for predict_name in sorted(os.listdir(PREDICT_TEXT_DATA_DIR)):
    predict_path = os.path.join(PREDICT_TEXT_DATA_DIR, predict_name)
    if os.path.isdir(predict_path):
        for predict_fname in sorted(os.listdir(predict_path)):
            if predict_fname.isdigit():
                predict_fpath = os.path.join(predict_path, predict_fname)
                if sys.version_info < (3,):
                    f = open(predict_fpath)
                else:
                    f = open(predict_fpath, encoding='latin-1')
                predict_text = f.read()
                i = predict_text.find('\n\n')  # skip header
                if 0 < i:
                    predict_text = predict_text[i:]
                predict_texts.append(predict_text)
                f.close()
print('Found %s texts.' % len(predict_texts))
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(predict_texts)
predict_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(predict_texts)
predict_data = pad_sequences(predict_sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
print('Shape of predict data tensor:', predict_data.shape)

x_predict = predict_data
y_predict = pretrained_model.predict(x_predict)
max_val = np.argmax(y_predict)
print('Category it belongs to : ',max_val)
```

The problem that I am facing now is that each time I run this above piece of code, `max_val` is always a different value.
How do I make predictions consistent please ?

Comment: What is the `tokenizer`, and are you training it with `tokenizer.fit_on_texts`? -- If so, you're probably recreating a model and training it every time you run the code. That explains your problem. (Some solutions, which fail on Tensorflow according to some questionss here, is to always set a random seed: `numpy.random.seed(someNumber)`.

Comment: @daniel I think you are right. I am retraining the tokenizer. How can I stop retraining tokenizer and still predict ? I am still new to Keras .

Comment: I don't know what kind of model the `tokenizer` is. You must search about it to know how to save and load its weights. Instead of training the tokenizer, you just load its already trained weights. (Maybe you train only the first time). --- A not so pretty solution is to remove the `fit_on_texts` line when you run it for the second time (depending on whether you're using a shell, for instance, the tokenizer will keep in memory as it is).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should predict one by one, not merge all texts for all files.

The following code I tested is OK:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Embedding
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 1000
MAX_NB_WORDS = 20000
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100

model = load_model('embedding.h5')

PREDICT_TEXT_DATA_DIR = 'predict_data'
predict_path = os.path.join(PREDICT_TEXT_DATA_DIR, '1.txt')
f = open(predict_path, encoding='utf-8')
predict_text = f.read()
f.close()

texts=[predict_text]
# finally, vectorize the text samples into a 2D integer tensor
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)

x_predict = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
print('Shape of predict data tensor:', x_predict.shape)

y_predict = model.predict(x_predict)
max_val = np.argmax(y_predict)
print('Category it belongs to : ',max_val)
```